# Architecture in handling Tokens (NodeJS) (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, authentication, token

I would like to know advantages and disadvantages of the following options to handle tokens correctly:

**Option A:**

(In Back-end) api.login(user) >> (success with Passport) >> createOrUpdateToken >> toSaveTokenIn**UserDocument** >> return User >> (In Front-end) toSavetokenUserInFrontEnd(window.localStorage.setItem)

**Option B:**

(In Back-end) api.login(user) >> (success with Passport) >> createOrUpdateToken >> toSaveTokenIn**TokenDocument** >> return User&Token >> (In Front-end) toSavetokenUserInFrontEnd(window.localStorage.setItem)

What is the right choise? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking is primarily a database question: should you store your tokens inside of your User document? Or inside of a separate Token document?

Here's my thoughts:

If you're using a NoSQL database (which I'm assuming you are), you're likely better off storing the token inside of the User document directly because this means you'll be able to avoid an expensive join operation.

Since tokens will be used on every API request, it'll be quite DB intensive to hit both collections every time, as opposed to just a User collection.

The same is true generally: any information that needs to be accessed frequently should most likely be denormalized for speed.

Hope this helps!